# How to can you let take your list the next character after 25 letters?

Tags: python, python-3.6

This is my code:

```
lijst = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'h', 'o', 'w', 'a', 'r', 'e','y','o','u', 'i', 's', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'r', 'y', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'n', 'e']

aa = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','j','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','d','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','k','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','i','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','u','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','x','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','l','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','h','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','t','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','q','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','z','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','n','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','p','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','y','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','f','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','v','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','o','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e','e']

for c in lijst:
    i = i+1

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('a',aa[((i))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('b',aa[((i+1))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('c',aa[((i+2))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('d',aa[((i+3))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('e',aa[((i+4))*25%650])  

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('f',aa[((i+5))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('g',aa[((i+6))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('h',aa[((i+7))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('i',aa[((i+8))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('j',aa[((i+9))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('k',aa[((i+10))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('l',aa[((i+11))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('m',aa[((i+12))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('n',aa[((i+13))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('o',aa[((i+14))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('p',aa[((i+15))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('q',aa[((i+16))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('r',aa[((i+17))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('s',aa[((i+18))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('t',aa[((i+19))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('u',aa[((i+20))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('v',aa[((i+21))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('w',aa[((i+22))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('x',aa[((i+23))*25%650])

    lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('y',aa[((i+24))*25%650])
```

I want an output of:

```
['H', 'a', 'a', 'i', 'k', 'j', 's', 'k', 'i', 'a', 'k', 'j', 's', 'a', 'b', 'd', 'l', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'e', 'p', 'd', 'd', 'i', 'v', 'e']
```

That works now, but I have a list of 250 character, is there an more pythonical way to do this? I want a list of 26 character(the same list, but each character only once) and I want the same output?
Thank you!

Comment: I honestly have no idea what your code is doing. Is this some kind of cipher? What is the cipher function (mathematically)? Could you please explain what the code is at least trying to do.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. trying to understand what you are doing, are you trying to increment simple encryption by translation ?

Comment: I am trying to make an enigma cipher machine.

Comment: are you looking for: https://py-enigma.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I am trying to make it myself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit:
First,you have to make a dictionary for all the substitutes, like this:

```
subs = {'a':'@',
'b':'%',
'c':'*'
}
```

etc.

For encryption,try this:

```
def encrypt(text):
    for c in text:
       text.replace(c, subs[c])
    return text

while True:
    text = str(input('>'))
    print(encrypt(text))
```

Comment: Do you mean no punctuation marks? Than yes, otherwise I don't understand the question.

Comment: I mean, do you want the english letters only? like: abcdefghijkl

Comment: Yes, I do only want the english letters.

Comment: It just gives my the alfabet.

Comment: wait, so you're trying to cipher it? Should've told me. I thought all you needed was the alphabet

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you knew it.

Comment: Check it now. just replace the dictionary values with your own

Comment: It doesn't have any output

Comment: Where do I have to add it?

Comment: like this:
`subs ={
'a':'b'
}


def encrypt(text):
    for c in text:
       text.replace(c, subs[c])
    return text

while True:
    text = str(input('>'))
    print(encrypt(text))
`

Comment: just put the code properly since i couldn't write it properly in a comment

Comment: And than, I have to write the original letter, colon and the new letter?

Comment: You know what dictionaries are? if not: check this out : https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/

Comment: So, would you mind accepting the answer? Well, you see I lost 2 out of the 3 reputation I had on this answer. An upvote or two would help

Answer (score 1):

You can create your aa list as such:

```
letters = ['a', 'j', 'd']  #The letters you want here
aa = []
for l in letters:
    aa += [l]*number_of_times_letter_should_be_repeated
```

Your for loop can be refactored like:

```
for i, c in enumerate(lijst):
    ascii = ord(c) - 97
    if ascii < 0 or ascii > 24:  # your code only goes to replacing y? otherwise put in 25.
        continue
    lijst[i] = aa[(i+ascii)*25%650]
```

the for loop without aa:

```
for i, c in enumerate(lijst):
    ascii = ord(c) - 97
    if ascii < 0 or ascii > 24:  # your code only goes to replacing y? otherwise put in 25.
        continue
    letters_index = round((i+ascii+1)*25%650)/25 - 0.5) #  Do check this because it isn't clear to me if this does what you are actually after.
    lijst[i] = aa[letters_index]
```

Comment: But ca I also not repeat the letters, and have a list of 26 letters and change lijst[i] = lijst[i].replace('a',aa[((i))*25%650]) , that i = i+1 after 25 letters?

Comment: So do you want the next letter in letters when the sum of the position in 'lijst' and position in the alphabet is larger than 25? That is not clear to me sorry. I've amended your (i+ascii)*25%650 formula and if that is larger than 25 go to the next letter.